# Minimizing Integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, maxima-minima

I tried to minimize below integral by finding field $\phi (x)$

$E = \int (D \ddot{\phi}^2(x) + C \dot{\phi}^2(x)) dx$

which $C$ and $D$ are constants.
Could anyone help me? any answers are highly appreciated.
 I could guess an answer by dimensional analysis, but it is not enough and I need a detailed answer.

Comment: do you know about euler-lagrange equations?

Comment: As I now it includes a first derivative, not second derivative. Could you solve the problem? @Basti